# Indexing sharepoint lists with ps

Tags: list, powershell, indexed-column

I would like to index a column in a list with powershell.

I have a problem, when i retrieve the list how can i set what field should be put to index? Is there a special command, can anyone provide me with example or give me a hint how to implement it.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can retrieve field form filed collection of a list and set Indexed property to true

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://sharepoint
$spList = $web.Lists["ListName"]
$spField = $spList.Fields["FieldName"]
$spField.Indexed = $true
$spField.Update()
```

Comment: why you say spTextField.Update? what is spTextFIeld?

Comment: sorry, I did mistake. I updated my unswer )

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to make attachments column in a list "NOT indexable"? if yes can you please post a script? including getting reference to that list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can you make two or three column indexed

Comment: How can I indexed two or three columns?